# How to implement async pipe in angular httpclient?

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-httpclient, angular-pipe

I was trying to load a child component based on data that will retrieve by HTTP get call. I was using a service to do the HTTP call and subscribing on the component's constructor. But the ngif was calling before the data retrieve.

so i have applied async pipe in the ngif but it is triggering another error.

service code:

```
GetContest(id){
    return this.http.get(this.baseurl+id);
}
```

constructor of component:

```
this.service.GetContest(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')).
    subscribe( (res)=> {
      this.contest = res;
      console.log(this.contest);
    });
```

template ngif:

```
<app-beforecontest *ngIf="contest.startTime<date "></app- 
beforecontest>
```

above codes generate an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTime' of null
```

and after this I joined async pipe like this:

```
<app-beforecontest *ngIf="(contest|async).startTime<date "></app- 
beforecontest>
```

and it is generating an error:

```
ContestComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object 
Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
at invalidPipeArgumentError
```

Comment: The async pipe works on *observables*, it's unclear why you expected it to work like that.

Answer (score 1):

The async pipe needs to be used on an observable, I created a simple stackblitz to show it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tx7g36

The main code you need to change is in the component itself

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ContestService} from './contest.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Contest startTime</h1>
    <p>{{(contest$ | async)?.startTime}}</p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  contest$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private contestService: ContestService) {
    this.contest$ = this.contestService.getContest();
  }
}
```

In case you wonder about the `$` at the end of the contest property, that's a notation to distinguish an observable from other types of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value of this.contest to null in your component.ts

```
this.contest = null
```

and in template check it like this:

```
<app-beforecontest *ngIf="contest?.startTime < date"></app- 
beforecontest>
```

@jonrsharpe Thanks for clearing this out

<del>note that `startTime<date ">` is a VERY wierd string and I don't know what you mean here.</del>

In general, if you want to use the async pipe you should use it on Observable:

```
myObservable$ = this.service.GetContest(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
```

**as you can see we did NOT `.subscribe` to it (!!!)**

and in template first async the observable and then add `.startTime`

```
<app-beforecontest *ngIf="(myObservable$ | async).startTime < date"></app-beforecontest>
```

Comment: *"very wierd string"* - it's a comparison, part of the conditional expression, maybe clearer as `...startTime < date"`

Answer (score -1):

In case of handling the async response and binding the template you could use safe naviagation operator as well like this -

```
<app-beforecontest *ngIf="contest?.startTime<date "></app- 
beforecontest>
```

Otherwise If you want to use async pipe you have to use it like below mannet -

```
<app-beforecontest *ngIf="contest.startTime | async"></app-beforecontest>
```

PS: But here in your case `contest` is not of asnyc in nature, you are just assigning it to value which is coming from async request. So better to use safe navigation operator `?`.

Comment: yes it is hiding the error but still the template ngif is checking the data before retrieving the httpcall. So my main problem is not solving.

Comment: what is the response you are getting in console for `console.log(this.contest);`?

Comment: https://ideone.com/YpGPpX see here for first console log in the subscribe the contest is printing rightly but for the second console log it is undefined

Comment: because your method returns result asynchronously, that's the reason second console is not getting defined. and first console will execute only when your request return success.

Comment: but it is not  solving my problem. then what is the solution?

Comment: Can you update me with your first console output? in share picture it is showing its empty

Comment: @lazyfahim at least you should remove the downvote for now.